# Positive Elements: Norm (Decomposition)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

Given a C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$.

Then every element decomposes into: $Z=X_+-X_-+iY_+-iY_-=\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}i^\alpha Z_\alpha$

Obviously, one has: $\|Z\|\leq\sum_{\alpha=0\ldots3}\|Z_\alpha\|$

> But what about the converse: $\|Z_\alpha\|\leq\|Z\|$

By continuous calculus it holds:
$$A=A^*:\quad \|A\|=\max\{\|A_+\|,\|A_-\|\}$$

So it remains to observe why: $\|X\|,\|Y\|\leq\|Z\|$

Here, I cannot make use of: $a,b\leq\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\quad(a,b\geq0)$

So how can I proceed then?

Comment: Stressing on real and imaginary part: $Z=X+iY$ Ignoring real and imaginary part: $Z=\sum_\alpha i^\alpha Z_\alpha$ I will add this! Did you mean that?

Comment: @JonasMeyer: Really, though the title conveys more information it is horrible pumped up. But even worse: When I or somebody else tries to find information on the norm of positive elements via search function or even google search he can't find this thread anymore, not at all. It simply misses those keywords in the whole thread. Please have a look on my sorting of threads. It has structure and I try to respect that "Branch: Keyword" is no good as there are the tags which are there therefor.

Comment: What does your question have to do with the norm of positive elements?  "Norm" already appears in the thread, and actually relevant keywords already appear in this thread, including "self-adjoint" which would have been in the more informative title.  I do not think that the uninformative title serves a purpose, and it makes it so that someone has to open the question to figure out what it is even about.  I am not attached to the particular phrasing you find "horrible pumped up," but I like question titles that say something useful about what the actual question is.

Comment: If interested in further meta discussion on the topic of (un)informative titles, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785/more-informative-titles, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/list-of-comment-templates/4931#4931, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16406/consider-giving-better-titles-to-the-questions-you-answered-especially-right (although yours don't tend to be as extreme as the examples given in a couple of those threads).

Comment: Yes, I know the have-to-open-threads is sort of a problem. But please please keep it short and "knackig". (Besides, thanks for the metas. :))

Comment: I have changed the title to something relatively concise, but that still says something relevant about the question.

Comment: I won't edit again.  I thought based on your last comment you were open to editing to a less vague and misleading title if it was more concise.  The title is uninformative, and you are not even asking about the norm of positive elements, so it also does not make sense to me even as a vague title. Finally I will leave it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $Z=X+iY$ with $X$ and $Y$ self-adjoint, note that $X=\frac12(Z+Z^*)$, and $Y=\frac1{2i}(Z-Z^*)$. Take norms, apply the triangle inequality, and recall that $\|Z^*\|=\|Z\|$ to conclude that $\|X\|\leq \|Z\|$ and $\|Y\|\leq \|Z\|$.

Comment: So easy, nice. :D